# Different methods for constructing the same empty nested list in python results in inconsistent behaviour

Tags: python, nested

I'm using Python 2.7.12.

I'm having a problem that I think is best explained through example.  Why does the `.append()` behaviour of `c` differ from `a` and `b`?

```
#Three different but equivalent methods to construct empty list:

a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append([])

b = [[] for _ in range(10)]

c = [[]]*10

print a
print b
print c

#Check to make sure they're equivalent. They are.
print a==b
print b==c
print a==c

#Carry out the same operation on all lists
a[1].append(6)
b[1].append(6)
c[1].append(6)

#Woah!  c is now different than a and b!
print a
print b
print c

print a==b
print b==c
print a==c
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
True
True
True
[[], [6], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[], [6], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]
True
False
False
```

Comment: I think that in `a` & `b` it is creating a list with 10 different empty lists. Whereas, `c` is a list of the same 10 lists. So if you change the first list in `c` all the others are also changed.

Comment: Similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Another dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/748858

Comment: Common Python gotcha: `[[]]*10` creates 10 references to the same empty list. Consider `li=[1]; li2=[li]*10; li2[0][0]=22` Try that...

Comment: @mgilson: Your dup is better. Can close as dupe with that reference?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way you've created `c`, all the lists are the same. Therefore appending to one will append to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine just enlightened me and I'll post it here in case it helps others.

```
c=[[]]*10
```

builds a list of lists that all point to the same memory location, and thus all elements will always be identical.  As a demonstration, setting the first element of the first sub-list to 10,

```
c[0][0]=10
print c
```

produces

```
[[10], [10], [10], [10], [10], [10], [10], [10], [10], [10]]
```

Comments on *why* this behaves as it does would be well received.

Comment: To answer the _why_, consider `lst = [[a, b, c]]; lst2 = lst * 2`.  Spread out across 2 lines, it becomes easier to see that there isn't really any reason that multiplying a list _should create new_ instances.  Indeed, I haven't even specified what `a`, `b` and `c` _are_.  Creating a (deep) copy of them could be expensive and (AFAIK) python never deep copies something unless you ask for it to explicitly.

Comment: Perfect, this is very clear!

Answer (score 0):

This creates a list of 10 independent empty lists:

```
b = [[] for _ in range(10)]
```

This creates a list of 10 copies of the same empty list:

```
c = [[]]*10
```

In other words, `c[0]` and `c[1]`, etc., all refer to the same empty list.  Changing `c[0]` is the same thing as changing `c[1]`.

#### Example

In Cpython, there is a function `id` to determine the identity of an object.  First, let's create b:

```
>>> b = [[] for _ in range(10)]
>>> id(b[0]) == id(b[1])
False
```

As you can see, `b[0]` and `b[1]` are different objects.

Now, let's create `c`:

```
>>> c = [[]]*10
>>> id(c[0]) == id(c[1])
True
```

By contrast, `c[0]` and `c[]1]` refer to the same (mutable) object.  Thus, modifying the list referred to by `c[0]` modifies them all:

```
>>> c[0].append(6)
>>> c
[[6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]
```

Instead of modifying a mutable object, it is possible, to make `c[0]` refer to a *different* object:

```
>>> c[0] = 'new'
>>> c
['new', [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]
```